# Show activity Indicator while uitableview reloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4.1

I have view with news in tableView, when I change some parameters in settings and return to view with news, my tableView must reloads news depending on new settings.
I have outlet activityIndicator and this code :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Start animating
    indicator.startAnimating()
    indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // Load new depending on settings    
    getJsonFromUrl(editionsArray: GlobalSettings.sharedManager.editions.sorted())
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    indicator.stopAnimating()
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
}
```

Now when tableView is empty I can see activityIndicator, but when my tableView reloads, activityIndicator is not shown on screen.

Comment: show that code getJsonFromUrl method

Comment: Check the UITableView is above activity indicator. Try the following code above `indicator.startAnimating()`  `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: indicator)`

Comment: @FebinFathah this code does not work for me

Comment: @Anbu.karthik 
It is simple method. I get son and parse in news array

Comment: oksy show that code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik https://gist.github.com/g196et/90df47d36b92ebfa1f25c44e0723420f

Comment: its `getJsonFromUrl ` in the same VC or else

Comment: Can you share me the view hierarchy of table and activity indicator?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes

Comment: @g196et - are you tried my answer

Answer (score 1):

Either the ActivityIndincatior behind the table view or table view cell color and activity indicator color will be matching (White in this case).

Also try by setting ActivityIndicator visibility true before animation start.

Hope you have not removed activity indicator form its sueprview.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I find the answer. All problems were in the function getJsonFromUrl, because I use a semaphore to wait for loading and parsing json. When I changed the semaphore to DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter everything started working!